# In the sentence"I break them all in the shop", what is the part of speech of "all" and what does "all" modify ?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> One day Joseph's mother asks him to go to the shop and buy some
>   eggs.
>
> "Be careful. Don't choose any bad ones," his mother says to him.
>
> After an hour, Joseph comes back with a
>   yellow plastic bag. His mother takes the bag and looks inside.
>
> "Oh!"she said, "What is it?"
>
> "Eggs!"Joseph says, "I break them ***all*** in the shop.Everyone is good!"

In the sentence "I break them all in the shop", what is the part of speech of "all" and what does "all" modify?

Comment: We `all` went to the ball game. = All of us went to the ball game. I broke them `all`. = I broke `all of` them.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, it should be "I *broke* them all in the shop." [Use past tense.]

So, **all** can be several parts of speech. I will give you a dictionary listing that I could think of.

*adj*.

> - Being or representing the entire or total number, amount, or quantity: All the windows are open. Deal all the cards. See synonyms at whole.
> - Every and any: got into all manner of trouble.

*n*.

> - The whole of one's fortune, resources, or energy; everything one has: The brave defenders gave their all.

*pron.*

> - The entire or total number, amount, or quantity; totality: All of us are sick. All that I have is yours.
> - Everyone; everything: justice for all.
>     adv.
> - Wholly; completely: a room painted all white; directions that were all wrong.
> - Each; apiece: a score of five all.
> - So much: I am all the better for that experience.

In your sentence, *all* is an adjective (of quantity) that modifies the object *them*. Not a *noun*, nor a *pronoun*. I think, the *all* is used for emphasis purpose. 
The evidence to that, is that the *all* can be removed (which means the *them* is still understandable), and the word *all* is stating that all of the eggs (the number of them) were broken.

But if you took the *all* as an noun or a pronoun, it should not be removable from the sentence.
It should be like:

> - I broke all in the shop. [Which *all*?] --> If this were a *noun* or a *pronoun*.

Answer (score 0):

All is adjective because it modifies the object of the verb break. Here them is object and all refers to the all egg

Comment: This doesn't really add to the other answer.